# Literature search for Isometric boundaries between signed distance functions

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

I have a bunch of signed distance functions representing non-overlapping objects in 3d space. I would like to find boundaries between the these signed distance functions such that the boundary marks the surface that is maximally distant to its own sdf while not being closer to any other sdf present in the volume. What is the problem I am trying to solve called? I want to organize a literature search around it, but find it hard to put it into words.

Comment: Do you know Voronoi tessellations ?

Comment: No answer to my very simple question ...